# kdb getting float from integer division

Tags: kdb

I have a table

```
id, turnover, qty
```

and I want to query

```
select sum turnover, sum qty, (sum turnover) div (sum qty) by id from Table
```

However, the the resulting value from the division seems to be an int and shows 0 (as the unit price is a lot smaller than 1). I tried to cast the results into a float, but that doesnt help

```
select sum turnover, sum qty, `float$(`float$(sum turnover) div `float$(sum qty)) by id from Table.
```

How can I get a float in return?
Also, as a side question. How can I name the column (equivalently to sql select sum(x) as my_column_name ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected output from div, you should use % to divide numbers - which always returns a float.

```
q)200 div 8.5
22
q)200%8.5
23.52941
q)
```

Reference here; 
Div:  http://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-integer/#div
%:    http://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-float/#divide

*edit

Apologies - forgot to reference the rest of your question. In your example, you are calculating the sum turnover and sum qty twice - you will want to avoid that, if you're dealing with a lot of records.

How is this;

```
    q)show trade:([] id:(`$"A",'string[til 10]);turnover:10?til 10; qty:10?100+til 200)
    id turnover qty
    ---------------
    A0 4        152
    A1 4        238
    A2 2        298
    A3 2        268
    A4 7        246
    A5 2        252
    A6 0        279
    A7 5        286
    A8 7        245
    A9 5        191
    q)update toverq:sumT%sumQ from select sumT:sum turnover,sumQ:sum qty by id from trade
    id| sumT sumQ toverq     
    --| ---------------------
    A0| 4    152  0.02631579 
    A1| 4    238  0.01680672 
    A2| 2    298  0.006711409
    A3| 2    268  0.007462687
    A4| 7    246  0.02845528 
    A5| 2    252  0.007936508
    A6| 0    279  0          
    A7| 5    286  0.01748252 
    A8| 7    245  0.02857143 
    A9| 5    191  0.02617801
```